# How to stop progress bar if information entered does not meet requirements?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I have a basic user registration page where a user signs up by entering a username and password. If the password is shorter than 6 characters the submission should not go through and a Toast appears, however in my code the progress bar will appear and wont disappear, how do I fix this?

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

      //  mProgress.setMessage("Signing up...");
       // mProgress.show();



        if (password.length()<6){

            Toast.makeText(VendorRegistration.this,"Passwords must contain at least 6 charachters",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        progress1.setMessage("Registering...");
        progress1.show();`
```

Comment: post more code.

Comment: progress1.disable() should do your job.

Comment: Are you familiar with `else`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the corrected code:

```
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            if (password.length()<6){
                Toast.makeText(VendorRegistration.this,"Passwords must contain at least 6 charachters",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else 

{  progress1.setMessage("Registering...");
            progress1.show();
// you can show progress only when all conditions become true.
}`
```